# "|" usually means "condition on", is this what it does mean here?

Tags: probability, notation

Page 68 in [pattern recognition and machine learning (free)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) uses this form

$p(x = 1|μ) = μ$

to denote the probability of a single binary random variable x = 1.

"|" usually means "condition on", is this what it does mean here?

Comment: For it to make any sense $\mu$ ought to be in $[0,1]$ and $x$ should depend on $\mu$. A more conventional notation and setting might be: conditional on $U=u$, suppose $X\sim \mathcal{B}(u)$, a Bernoulli RV with parameter $u$, where $U$ is any RV with values in the unit interval. Then $\mathbb{P}(X=1|U=u)=u$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I am aware that X denotes a random variable. Does U denote another random variable that plays a role of the parameter of distribution?

Comment: Yes. Feller called this “randomization” (i.e. randomizing the parameters of a given distribution). It’s also a pretty central technique to Bayesian theory, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thanks for your comments. Is Feller [this guy](https://scholar.harvard.edu/feller)?

Comment: Nope, William Feller, sorry I should have specified. If you can find a scan or real copy of his classic textbook, in volume 2, chapter 2, he goes over a handful of randomizations for both discrete RVs and continuous RVs, randomizing their parameters in interesting ways and briefly explaining applications to physics, queues, random walks etc. But this is an old and classic reference, so probably more informative than immediately useful for machine learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that means that the probability of the event $x=1$ given that the parameter $\mu$ is equal to $\mu$ (another words, given the value of $\mu$) is equal to $\mu$.